# Backbone collection View add not being called with a model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I've my models

```
var Client = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var Colony = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/presence/knock',
    model: Client
});
```

views

```
var ClientView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
    },
    template: _.template('...'),
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
var ColonyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'addOne', 'addAll');

        this.collection.bind('add', this.addOne);
        this.collection.bind('refresh', this.addAll);
        this.collection.bind('change', this.addAll);
    },
    addOne: function(item){
        console.log('addOne', item);
        var view = new ClientView({
            model: item
        });
        $(this.el).append(view.render().el);
    },
    addAll: function(){
        var self = this;
        this.collection.each(function(item){
            self.addOne(item);
        });
    },
    render: function(){
        this.addAll();
        return this;
    }
});
```

and I update the collection with a comet on `/presence/knock`.

```
var colony = new Colony([{
    ip: '127.0.0.1',
    name: 'localhost.localdomain',
    lsup: 'now'
}]);
setInterval(function(){
    colony.fetch({
        update: true
    });
}, 5*1000);

var colonyView = new ColonyView({
    collection: colony
});
$("#clients-board").append(colonyView.render().el);
```

First time when the colonyview is rendered `addOne` gets a client as argument, because its called through addAll. but next time when `addOne` is called through `add` event I see in inspector `item` is not a `client`

> r {cid: "c606", attributes: Object, collection: r, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object…}

Comment: r {cid: "c606", attributes: Object, collection: r, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object…}  is a model object extended from backbone.model. It can be an instance of client model. maybe you can log item.toJSON() to see the properties

Comment: I think you have to write colony.fetch({update: true, remove: false}). Without the remove the "add" event isn't triggered for every new model. http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch

Comment: @nilgundag I checked item.toJSON() in addOne it is `Object {clients: Array[1]}` which is a colony (collection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i figured out your problem.

Here is a working fiddle with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/nilgundag/KbwHZ/

I have used mockjax to mock the server and here what it returns:

```
[{
    ip: '127.0.0.1',
    name: 'localhost.localdomain',
    lsup: 'now'
},
{
    ip: '127.0.0.2',
    name: 'localhost.localdomain',
    lsup: 'now'
}]
```

Since you said you are getting Object {clients: Array[1]}, probably your server returns:

```
[{
        clients:[{
                ip: '127.0.0.1',
                name: 'localhost.localdomain',
                lsup: 'now'
        }]
}]
```

Here is fiddle which demonstrates your case: http://jsfiddle.net/nilgundag/TxZxp/

You should change your server code to only send the client array, not an object containing a property clients and the associated array.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I also saw in morning. I overridden the `parse` method and returned `clients`

Comment: now the problem is `collection.fetch{update: true}` not merging properly. I am using `ip` field as `idAttribute` is My `Client` Model But still It `add`s everything instead of merging

Comment: var Client = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute : "ip"
}); works in the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nilgundag/KbwHZ/

Comment: Yes I see its working. in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QTchC/. I've to check why its not working in actual scenario. Thanks

Comment: It actually adds everything and it doesn't obey the id attribute. I've posted a different question for that on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054359/backbone-collection-fetch-with-update-true-adding-same-model-always It will be great If you can help