# Backbone collection.fetch({update: true}) doesn't compare id add's same model again

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In relation with My another question on [Backbone collection View add not being called with a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964354/backbone-collection-view-add-not-being-called-with-a-model)

I've my models

```
var Client = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: 'ip'
});
var Colony = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/presence/knock',
    model: Client
});
```

I've also tried

```
var Client = Backbone.Model.extend({
    ipAttribute: function(){
        return this.options.ip
    }
});
```

I've also tried using the `id` attribute instead of using `ip`. But nothing works. It seems Backbone is comparing the **whole** object. **not** the `idAttribute` So If two objects are `EXACTLY` same its not triggering `add` However If there is any change which is not in `idAttribute` is still thinks the model is new and triggers `add`

I've a Fiddle on [`http://jsfiddle.net/3QE3u/`](http://jsfiddle.net/3QE3u/) that uses mock ajax (based on the solution of the above mentioned question that I asked few days ago).

Comment: Yes sorry. Its supposed to be idAttribute

Comment: can you make sure that 'ip' on your back end is unique ?

Comment: Yes they are unique. and you can see in fiddle. with mockajax `ip` is unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If there is any change which is not in idAttribute is still thinks
>   the model is new and triggers add

In your code in the fiddle you have also binded "change" event of the collection to "addAll" function

```
this.collection.bind('change', this.addAll);
```

If you comment this line, your code will work as you expected.

Here it how it works now:
When first fetch function is called "add" event is fired for the item with ip "127.0.0.2" and "change" is fired for the item with ip "127.0.0.1". When fetch function is called for the second time "change" event is fired for both items. For each consecutive call to fetch, "change" event is fired for two items. (side note: refresh event is never trigger at all)

You can write another method to handle the "change" event and in that method you can update existing html element to reflect the update.